# kafka server getting crashed on windows environment after certain time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm currently trying some tests which includes Kafka to send and receives messages. In my application, I've simple kafka producer which periodically produces the message and the Kafka receiver application receives it. But after running this application for about 36-37 hours Kafka server is getting crashed with below error. I've went through [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6188) also, but this seems little different issue than what I'm currently facing. I'm using Kafka 2.4.0 on windows machine locally.

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\kafka\temp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-9\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned -> C:\kafka\temp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-9\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:795)
    at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.renameTo(AbstractIndex.scala:209)
    at kafka.log.LogSegment.changeFileSuffixes(LogSegment.scala:497)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$replaceSegments$4(Log.scala:2286)
    at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$replaceSegments$4$adapted(Log.scala:2286)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at kafka.log.Log.replaceSegments(Log.scala:2286)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.cleanSegments(LogCleaner.scala:605)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.$anonfun$doClean$6(LogCleaner.scala:530)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.$anonfun$doClean$6$adapted(LogCleaner.scala:529)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.doClean(LogCleaner.scala:529)
    at kafka.log.Cleaner.clean(LogCleaner.scala:503)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanLog(LogCleaner.scala:372)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:345)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.tryCleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:325)
    at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.doWork(LogCleaner.scala:314)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
    Suppressed: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\kafka\temp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-9\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned -> C:\kafka\temp\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-9\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
            at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
            at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:792)
            ... 17 more
```

**FYI**: I'm using Kafka with all default configurations and creating topics with different no of partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop Kafka and zookeeper properly. if still, the problem is there then you need to delete the C:\kafka\temp\kafka-logs\ and then start the server.

You will lose your data and the offset will start from 0.

Comment: This solution is not really helpful on production environment, as it not only involve manual intervention,also it wipes out your data and metadata.

Comment: Actually this issue is still open.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6200

Comment: This issue is already addressed by kafka team [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7278). But this is different issue, as this is kafka start up error. In my case, I'm able to start kafka server and run the test for about 40hrs, then it crashes with above exception. I'm not worried much about the error getting while starting kafka server up again as it is obvious that it will be in dirty state when exited with such error. I'm more interested in what is causing this exception in the first place after running properly for that long.